# Как сделать backup базы данных на более раннею версию в MSSQL

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Нужно развернуть базу данных для сайта на сервере.  Админы ответили что моя резервная копия не поддреживается их серваком. У них более раняя версия. Как мне сделать бекап на версию раньше в MSSQL Man Studio, может и другая прога понадобится..а не потив. Вот сообщение:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Создание резервной копии баз данных производилось на сервере, на котором работала версия 13.00.4001. Эта версия несовместима с данным сервером, на котором работает версия 12.00.5000. Либо восстановите базу данных на сервере, который поддерживает эту резервную копию, либо воспользуйтесь резервной копией, совместимой с данным сервером. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В виде бэкапов - никак.

Возможные варианты:

- Заскриптовать в виде SQL: Tasks -> Generate Scripts -> all tables + в настройках advanced заменить Types of data to script с Schema only на Schema and Data. Dыполнить полученный скрипт на сервере.
- Экспортировать в bacpac, и импортировать на сервере. Через  SMSS - Import / Export Data Tier Application, или с помощью утилиты [sqlpackage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017). Перед экспортом стоит снизить Compatibility Level у базы до 120.

Comment: На данный момент первый вариант не могу провернуть Второй не совсем понятен. Скачал по ссылке sqlpackage. Установил. Я так понимаю она уставливается сразу на сервер. Каким образом мне ей воспользоваться?

Comment: Первым способом смог на их сервере сделать. Все ок. Спасибо!

Comment: @FX_Sektor на всякий случай, вдруг пригодится в будущем - sqlpackage устанавливается на клиенте,  ей можно указать сервер и базу в параметрах. Но проще сделать импорт экспорт через SSMS