# База данных в Sql Server

Tags: sql

Есть база данных созданная в Sql Server 2017 (на Windows 10). Можно ли использовать эту базу в Sql Server 2014 (на Windows 7)?
И как базу переносить? Делать бэкап? С младшей версии на более старшую все работает, а наоборот будет работать?

Comment: Можно понизить compatibility level базы до совместимого, конечно, и переаттачить... но через бэкап (и всё равно - с понижением, а то не восстановится) оно спокойнее.

Comment: @Akina через бэкап даже с понижением compatibility level не перенесется.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать backup базы данных на более раннею версию в MSSQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/873087/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-backup-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-mssql)

Comment: @PashaPash Почему? понижаем compatibility level базы, делаем бэкап... должно восстанавливаться нормально, вроде... во всяком случае я что-то подобное проделывал, перенося БД с 2005 на 2000 - прокатило.

Comment: @Akina больше не прокатывает. У бэкапов теперь своя версионность, оно даже на более старый патч того же sql server может не поднять бэкап.

Comment: @PashaPash Что-то подумал... а зеркалировать на более старую версию при совместимом compatibility level - можно?

Comment: @Akina для зеркала нужен первоначальный backup + transaction logs, так что нет. Из надежных вариантов - Import / Export Data Tier Application. Там есть свои особенности - логины не переносятся, timestamp перенумеровывается с нуля, но лучше, чем ничего.